# How would you show that a non-cyclic group of order 10 must contain an element of order 5?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups, group-isomorphism

How would you show that a non-cyclic group of order 10 must contain an element $r$ of order 5?

Also, is every pair of groups homomorphic?

Thanks

Comment: For the first question, do you have any thoughts? Do you know the possible orders of the group elements? For the second: "homomorphic" is not a property of a group that I know of, what is it?

Comment: No, I'm not really sure at all. I know that the order of a group refers to the number of elements in it, and the order of an element is the number of times you can operate on itself before the identity element is obtained. I'm not sure, however, what the link is between the order of a group and the order of the elements in it.

Comment: It holds for the cyclic group of order 10 too ...

Answer (score 5):

Let $G$ be a group of order $10$ with no element of order $5$. By Lagrange's theorem, all elements would have order $2$ (except $e$) and so $G$ would be abelian. Let $a, b \in G$ of order $2$. Then $\{e,a,b,ab\}$ would be a subgroup of order $4$, which cannot happen because $4$ does not divide $10$.